# Obtener Fechas solo de Dia-mes-Año sin Horas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

¿Cómo puedo obtener fechas sin horas ni minutos en una consulta de SQL para utilizar un `COUNT`? Necesito que me muestre la cantidad repetida y día que se realizó. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Ojo, no es MySQL necesito es para SQL server 2008 R2

```
  SELECT TOP 2000 
    a.UserID,
    (a.CharName) as maton,
    (a.DeadCharName) as Victima,
    (b.[level])as nivel_de_Victima, 
    COUNT (a.DeadCharName) As  Veces,
    a.actiontime <<---- Campo Fecha a selecionar
    FROM PS_GameLog.dbo.Kill_Log a
    INNER JOIN PS_GameData.dbo.Chars b
    on a.CharID = b.CharID
    WHERE a.CharID = 62336
    ORDER BY Veces DESC
    GROUP BY a.UserID,a.CharName,a.DeadCharName,b.[level] 
    ORDER BY Veces DESC
```

Ejemplo, de fechas en que formato están, necesito tomar los 11 dígitos obvio incluyendo los guiones.

```
2016-12-23 15:42:29.000
2016-12-23 15:42:28.000
2016-12-23 15:42:30.000
```

Comment: Revisa http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp y por favor, busca en internet e intenta resolverlo por ti mismo antes de  postear preguntas.

Comment: @MikeVelazco ese link que envías aplica para MySQL y la pregunta va enfocada a SQL Server

Comment: OK, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si tienes SQL Server 2008+, puedes convertirlo a `DATE`:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 a.UserID,
                a.CharName as maton,
                a.DeadCharName as Victima,
                b.[level] as nivel_de_Victima, 
                COUNT(a.DeadCharName) as Veces,
                CONVERT(DATE,a.actiontime) ActionTime
FROM PS_GameLog.dbo.Kill_Log a
INNER JOIN PS_GameData.dbo.Chars b
    ON a.CharID = b.CharID
WHERE a.CharID = 62336
GROUP BY a.UserID,
         a.CharName,
         a.DeadCharName,
         b.[level],
         CONVERT(DATE,a.actiontime)
ORDER BY Veces DESC;
```

Si no, puedes convertirlo a un string que contenga sólo el año, mes y día:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 a.UserID,
                a.CharName as maton,
                a.DeadCharName as Victima,
                b.[level] as nivel_de_Victima, 
                COUNT(a.DeadCharName) as Veces,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),a.actiontime,112) ActionTime
FROM PS_GameLog.dbo.Kill_Log a
INNER JOIN PS_GameData.dbo.Chars b
    ON a.CharID = b.CharID
WHERE a.CharID = 62336
GROUP BY a.UserID,
         a.CharName,
         a.DeadCharName,
         b.[level],
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),a.actiontime,112)
ORDER BY Veces DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir el campo fecha al formato `YYYY-MM-DD` en SQL Server 2008 R2, puedes usar la función `CONVERT` con los parámetros siguientes:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.actiontime, 23)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/NNFY14544)</kbd>

Si el formato que quieres es mas bien `DD-MM-YYYY`, entonces sería de esta forma:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.actiontime, 105)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/UUKIJ73815)</kbd>

---

> ¿Cómo puedo obtener fechas sin horas ni minutos en una consulta de SQL ***para utilizar un `COUNT`***?

Si simplemente necesitas la porción fecha sin la hora para poder hacer una cuenta, entonces el formato del campo no tiene importancia. En este caso, lo más sencillo es de simplemente hacer un `CAST` a tipo `DATE`:

```
CAST(a.actiontime AS DATE)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/UOC46931)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

En una versión más antigua de SQL (donde no funciona `CONVERT(DATE,a.actiontime)`), he usado:

```
cast(floor(cast(a.actiontime as float)) as datetime)
```

A la fecha la paso a FLOAT, luego hallo su parte entera (quitando de esta forma la hora), finalmente se vuelve a convertir en fecha.